# Is it permissible to open the mosque for the foreigner tourists?

Tags: non-muslim, masjid

Mosque's main purposes is the place to offer our prayers and preaching of Islam. During my visit to Istanbul recently, I saw the mosques were closed at the prayer times but after that the mosque was open for the foreigners to visit and see. Kindly let me know if it is permissible or not?